# Give double bounties

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, bounty

Users are fairly attached to their reputation. Nobody likes giving it away and therefore, raising a bounty can be tough.

My suggestion is that a bounty doubles in value when you award them. So, if you place a 200 rep bounty, you spend only 100.

This way, more bounties will be awarded and the reputation will generally inflate.

Does this sound like a good idea?

Comment: As a moderator, seeing the words "reputation" and "inflate" in the same sentence makes me twitch.

Comment: This is not how bounties work, or how math works, for that matter.

Comment: It is only half a proposal.  While this may easily double the number of questions with bounties, it does not propose how to double the number of users that answer them.  So in the end, what you really accomplish is that users now only have half a chance to get an answer.

Comment: I wrote a bit of diatribe against this, but I could distill it to this:  no, you have to pay for the bounty yourself.  If you're worried about losing the reputation, then don't place the bounty.

Comment: double jeopardy!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not viable.

We don't want reputation to inflate, nor do we need it to, because rep is a standard measure – it's not a currency. We don't *need* a certain amount of rep to go around or be "in circulation" because upvotes are and always have been free. You can give others reputation (and, on questions), take it away, without it affecting your reputation.

Bounties are a relatively rare (in comparison to upvotes) exception to this and are not the most common way of gaining reputation for most users.

Imagine the gaming that would occur if this is implemented – User A places a bounty on User B's question for 100 rep. User B is awarded 200 rep and places a bounty on User A's question for 200 rep. User A is awarded 400 rep and places a bounty on User B's question for 400 rep. User B is awarded 800 rep...and so on, until they decide to split the earnings.

The associated risks outweigh any advantages here.